# How to require static images using programmatic paths?

Tags: webpack, next.js

Trying to require images using programmatic paths so they can processed by Next.js.

Following works

```
import Image from "next/image"

…

<Image
  …
  src={require(`../docs/${props.value}/cover.jpg`)}
/>
```

But following doesn’t likely because of missing file extension.

```
import Image from "next/image"

const cover = "cover.jpg"

…

<Image
  …
  src={require(`../docs/${props.value}/${cover}`)}
/>
```

Is there a way to circumvent this?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Where are you importing your images from?

Comment: Have you explored moving the images to `public` directory? Then, you could use then public path directly `/${props.value}/cover.jpg`. Or, if you don't want to have the images in the public directory in the codebase, you could create a small script that copies the images to the `public` directory and add it in your build script. "build": "./moveImagesToPublic.sh && next build"

Comment: @vighnesh153 Trying to avoid using `/public` paths and use automatic blur hash.